# Is there a darwin (arm64) equivalent of `O_PATH` for open?

Tags: system-calls, darwin, golang

I want to get the file descriptor without opening the file which can be attained by using the `O_PATH` flag on linux. ([ref](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html))

This flag doesn't seem to be there on darwin.

**Context**

- I'm trying to use `open` through Go's `syscall.Open`. ([ref](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Open))
- The `O_PATH` flag is defined in the `sys/unix` package (not for darwin though). ([ref](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sys/+/3681064d:unix/zerrors_linux_amd64.go;l=170))

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Please tell more about what you would like to achieve with that fd. Couldn't this be achieved through the *stat* system call ?

Comment: I was trying to get to whatever file metadata is available without opening it. Trying to do it in the fastest way possible. After reading a bit about stat (after seeing your reply) I think it does this but is platform-dependent.

Comment: If you’re after performance, have you profiled `open`/`fstat`/`close` (with `O_PATH` on Linux) v. `stat`? I’m not sure the former would be faster...

Comment: I haven't checked that, was going by the man page. `stat` using `syscall.Stat` seems to be much faster (~x5) than `syscall.Open`, `syscall.Fstat` and `syscall.Close` using `O_RDONLY`. 

Will have to check `stat` source to figure out if `O_PATH` would be any faster (don't have access to linux).

Unless there's something faster, `syscall.Stat` (`stat`) serves my purpose.

Comment: I wouldn’t even bother with `syscall.Stat`; `os.Stat` would be a better choice for most purposes.

Comment: What is your reason? There are pref gains to had with `syscall.Stat` w.r.t `os.Stat` which is slower than syscalls to `open`, `fstat` and `close`. The downside I see is that platform-specific code has to be written if using `syscall.Stat`.

Comment: Maintainability, but I haven’t done performance comparisons. The performance gain will depend on how much you need to extract from `fileStat`, I imagine if you don’t need everything then `syscall.Stat` + your own extraction code could be faster than `os.Stat`.